# Are subtitles included in Apple's App Store Search algorithm?

Tags: search, app-store, ios11

In iOS 11 Apple included a new metadata field in the App Store, "Subtitle". What I am wondering is if the subtitle is included in Apple's App Store Search algorithm, and is there anyway to know how it is weighted?

Apple explains their search algorithm contains a few new fields, but does not explicitly mention that subtitles are included, only that they are visible to the user in the results page.

> Search results now include developers, in-app purchases, categories,
>   editorial stories, tips and tricks, and collections. Apps appear in
>   search results with subtitles and a single rating prominently
>   displayed.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/search/

However, to contradict this I tested in an iOS 11 beta device, and I was able to get the correct app in the search results by entering an app's subtitle.

Is anyone aware of specific documentation that helps clarify the roles subtitles play in Apple's App Store Search functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Apple's App Store search algorithm includes the subtitle. Verified by searching for apps with unique subtitles that were not present in the description of the app.